# Pretty-print a Python expression that can be read but contains a comment

Tags: python, comments, pretty-print

I have a data structure which I'd like to print out in a form that is both human- and machine-readable. Specifically, I want to print it as a call to the constructor which would rebuild the same object if parsed as a Python expression.

The data structure can be inconsistent. (It won't be used in this inconsistent state unless the program is buggy.) If it is inconsistent, I would like to print it out as a call which builds a consistent object (I have a well-defined policy for resolving the inconsistency). However, I use prettyprinting heavily in debugging, so I would like to have some way of revealing the inconsistency. Thus for an inconsistent object, Python should see an expression to construct a consistent object but a human should see the inconsistency.

Here's a silly example. The `Sum` class's `sum` field should be the sum of `a` and `b`. If it isn't, `sum` is assumed to be wrong — but I want to see the wrong value of `sum` in the printout.

```
class Sum:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.update()
    def update(self):
        self.sum = self.a + self.b
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Sum(%s, %s)%s' % \
               (str(self.a), str(self.b),
                '' if self.sum == self.a + self.b else ' # sum=' + str(self.sum))
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = Sum(1, 2)
>>> str(x)
'Sum(1, 2)'
>>> x.a = 2
>>> str(x)
'Sum(2, 2) # sum=3'
```

This is not good because `Sum(2, 2) # sum=3` cannot be parsed as part of a larger expression. I don't want to rely on line breaks, either, as the printout could be copied around as text with line wrapping.

I could add an optional parameter to the constructor to build an inconsistent object, but it would be messy. Objects are never supposed to be created in an inconsistent state.

How else can I print something out that Python will parse but ignore?

Comment: Whatever code is supposed to deal with `x = Sum(1, 2) str(x) 'Sum(1, 2)' x.a = 2 str(x) 'Sum(2, 2)'` is clearly not just `eval`-ing the whole expression, so you must have written some simple parser that extracts the bits to `eval` later. It should be trivial to expand that parser to remove comments?

Comment: Also, it seems like this example would be better served by changing the constructor to take an optional `sum=None`, and `if sum is not None: assert sum == a + b` or something else appropriate, so you can just do `Sum(%s, %s) % (self.a, self.b) if self.sum == self.a + self.b else Sum(%s, %s, %s) % (self.a, self.b, self.sum)`… or, even more simply, `Sum(%s, %s, %s) % (self.a, self.b, self.sum)`.

Comment: And more generally, using `eval` as a serialization format is clunky, slow, unsafe, and hard to debug. Writing out code fragments that you can copy and paste and use at the interactive prompt, that's fine; writing out code fragments to parse and `eval` automatically is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry, I messed up the formatting — this was a transcript of a toplevel session. In real life I'm building bigger expressions like `Product(Sum(1, 2), 3)` which would be messed up as `Product(Sum(1, 2) # sum=3, 3)`. As I mentioned, I am considering adding an optional argument `DO_NOT_USE_sum`, but it's clunky. Coming with a Lisp background (among others), I don't understand why you don't like serializing data structures to executable code.

Comment: In Lisp, executable code, parse trees, and raw source code are the same thing. In Python, they're three different things, and raw source code is rarely the one you actually want. For example, building `Product(Sum(1, 2), 3)` out of ASTs (whether actual Python ASTs, or your own expression syntax) is much simpler than doing it with string formatting, and obviously more efficient and more robust to boot. And it wouldn't have this problem in the first place.'